# Why wasn't a Uchiha asked to control the Nine Tails during its attack?

Tags: naruto

Madara or Tobi had controlled the Nine Tails to attack Konoha during Naruto's birth. But there were other Uchihas in the village such as Itachi's father. So, the village could have made use of them to defend the Nine Tails by controlling it using their sharingan. Why didn't they do that?

Another question: Why were the three sannin not seen during the Nine Tails attack?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why no other Uchiha in Konoha was asked to take control of the Nine Tailed beast? - To control the nine tailed beast you need to be a shinobi of very high caliber. Being an Uchiha is just not enough to be able to control the nine tailed beast. Tobi had Hashirama's cells (in the form of Zetsu) infused in him that allowed him larger chakra and better control of the Nine Tails.

Where were the three sanins? - it has not been mentioned anywhere in the plot where they were, so all we can do is guess about their whereabouts. If they were in the village they would have surely come for help, and since they were absent from the battle, we can only guess that they were out of the village on some mission.

Answer (score 11):

As for the Uchiha, the nine tails was already being controlled by Tobi at the time, so I doubt anyone would be able to control him on top of that.

Not to mention, the Uchiha weren't exactly trusted at the time, following the Second Hokage's rule.

As for the three sannin, it wasn't explained anywhere, but it isn't hard to imagine them being at a remote mission and out of the village.

Comment: this answer is more correct then the accepted one. also about the sannin, they disbanded aster 3rd ninja war. so they went there separate ways.

Answer (score 2):

An Uchiha needs to have awakened the Mangekyu Sharingan in order to control the Kyuubi and Madara  and Tobi were the only two Uchihas who were able to achieve this followed by Itachi, Kakashi and Sasuke.

About the three Sanin, Jiraya was most probably training with Nagato and Konan, Orochimaru had defected from the village and Tsunade had left the village because she was unable to bear the trauma that came with death of her brother and lover.

Comment: Please could you explain as to where it has been mentioned that an Uchiha needs to have awakened the Mangekyou Sharingan in order to take control of the Kyubi. 
Also Dan was not Tsunade's husband, he was just her love.

Comment: When Sasuke learned of the Mangekyo inducing blindness, he said "so that's the price you pay to control the nine tails".

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing it out that Dan was not Tsunade's husband, have updated my answer. And the answer to your first question can be found here. http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mangeky%C5%8D_Sharingan

Comment: I'm not sure that your timeline adds up though. Jirayia was training with Nagato and the folks before Orochimaru defected from the village. Also Tsunade was still in fighting shape then.

Comment: I think there is a flaw in your timeline. Jiraya teaching Konan and group was during the third great ninja war, and Orochimaru defected after that.

Comment: didn't izuna and sasuke have mangekyo as well. and shusui also.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: The Uchiha Clan were distrusted by the village leadership and were ordered to not engage the Nine-Tails.

---

As per [Itachi Shinden](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Itachi_Shinden), the Uchiha Clan (which was the Konoha police force during the Nine-Tails' attack) were ordered by the village leadership ([Konoha Council](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Konoha_Council)) to protect the civilians in the village and not engage the Nine-Tails.

Uchiha Clan members believe that this was because they are distrusted by the village leadership. They also feel that they are being suspected to be what actually caused the Nine-Tails incident.

Indeed, after the Nine-Tails' attack, the Konoha Police headquarters (which sustained heavy damage) and the Uchiha Clan houses were ordered moved to the outskirts of the village, too far from the village center, despite Fugaku Uchiha's protest. (Fugaku is the head of the Uchiha Clan, and Itachi and Sasuke's father.) The location also can be easily spied upon from several vantage points as noticed by Fugaku, adding to feelings of distrust between the Uchiha Clan and the Konoha Council, culminating at the Uchiha Clan massacre.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason might be that: Not all Uchiha's are as powerful as you think. And not all of them are lucky enough to Awaken the mangekyou. They were a proud clan but not all their members were as strong as Madara or Itachi. Those 2 were like prodigies in their own ways.

Also, I doubt anyone at that time knew an Uchiha could control the Kyuubi. It was probably only Minato and Kushina that knew about the masked man and his Sharingan. No one else saw him and lived so it makes sense that their minds didn't think about it. In madara's case, It was probably a classified information that he fought by controlling the 9 tails. It makes sense that the higher ups would classify that type of information as secret cause they wouldn't want other Uchihas to go researching into how to control the Kyuubi.

As for the 3 Sanin, It makes sense to believe that they were on a mission, probably that timeline could fit into when Jiraiya was training nagato and his crew (Yahiko and Konan, This is just a vague guess btw).

Answer (score 0):

Only an Uchiha with the mangekyou sharingancan control the nine tails. Obito had obtained it after Rins death plus he had Hashirama cells to fall back on. The leaf village was not aware of fugaku having the mangekyou sharingan or else they would have feared him even more plus his people would have pressured him to attack the village.

To answer your question the leaf village feared that the Uchiha would done how gain control of the nine tails so that’s why three weren’t called to assist during the attack. It was stated by the Uchiha that they suspected this. The Sannin were always away on missions doing their own thing. They weren’t such a great asset to the village only Tsunade after becoming hokage.

In conclusion the Uchiha clan were always being discriminated against and treated like trash but then the leaf is surprised when they retaliate. The third hokage was the worse leader Kohona ever had. Yes naruto always forgave sasuke for his treachery but at the end sasuke changed. Danzō never did and he let Danzō get away with everything. He even ordered a 13 year old kid (Itachi) to kill his entire clan including his parents. He just used Danzō as the darkness he could never represent as him self.

Answer (score 0):

Fugaku uchiha had the mangekyõ sharingan at the time of the attack therefore he could've easily controlled the tailed beast. But he was ordered to stand down.

And as for the three sannin. Orochimaru was a rogue ninja at the time. Jiraiya was out doing research and hadn't heard about the attack. TSunade had quit being a shinobi.